# JavaFX: How to add CSS to an Image element in FXML

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml

I have the following FXML:

```xml
<VBox id="customerFormPane" styleClass="customerForm" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.customer.CustomerFormController" >
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@customerform.css"/>
    </stylesheets>

    <GridPane>
        <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" percentWidth="50.0"/>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" percentWidth="50.0"/>
        </columnConstraints>

        <ImageView id="boxImage" fitWidth="100" fitHeight="100">
            <image>
                <Image url="@/com/exmaple/resources/icons/office.png" />
            </image>            
        </ImageView>
    </GridPane>

</VBox>
```

I would like to define a border in CSS for the Image. I have tried this in customerform.css file:

```css
.customerForm Image, .customerForm ImageView, .customerForm image {

    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-border-style: solid;
    -fx-border-color: red;

}
```

But nothing happens, any tip on how to select the ImageView? (Note: the image is displayed correctly)

Answer (score 3):

CSS properties that are not supported by a node are simply ignored. In your case that's all those properties. `Region` provides the `-fx-background-color`, `-fx-border-style` and `-fx-border-color` properties, but `ImageView` is not a subclass of `Region`.

In order for this to work you'd need to wrap the image in a suitable type of `Region`.

Example:

```xml
<GridPane>
    <columnConstraints>
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" percentWidth="50.0"/>
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" percentWidth="50.0"/>
    </columnConstraints>
    <!-- container using pref size as max size to not grow larger than the image -->
    <Pane styleClass="image-container" maxWidth="-Infinity" maxHeight="-Infinity">
        <children>
            <ImageView id="boxImage" fitWidth="100" fitHeight="100">
                <image>
                    <Image url="@/com/exmaple/resources/icons/office.png" />
                </image>            
            </ImageView>
       </children>
    </Pane>
</GridPane>
```

```css
.image-container {
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-border-style: solid;
    -fx-border-color: red;
}
```

---

BTW: You seem to be unsure which selectors are the correct ones here. You need to use the node type in the selector. `.customerForm ImageView` or `#boxImage` would work as selectors.